# cannot find class DataContractJsonSerializer .net 4.0

Tags: .net

I am trying to create an object of DataContractJsonSerialize

using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json; does not work, I am using .Net 4.0
I have added a referece to System.ServiceModel.Web, i also have using System.ServiceModel.Web; in my using statements.

everywhere i read said to adda reference to System.ServiceModel.Web.dll, but that did not fix it for me

Comment: Its DataContractJsonSerializer, you are missing r at the end, is that a typo ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to MSDN, `DataContractJsonSerializer` is implemented in `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx

Make sure you have a reference to that assembly?

Comment: I had to dropped and recreated the reference to the assembly, then it worked!

Answer (score 2):

1. Search and add `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` in reference.
2. Then use in directive `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;`